# Help understanding gluLookAt()

Tags: opengl-es

Imagine you're standing on the ground looking up at a cube in the sky. As you tilt your head, the cube moves. I'm trying to replicate this using OpenGL ES on the iPhone by manipulating the tilt of the camera while looking at a simple 3D cube drawn around the origin. I'm using the `gluLookAt()` function from Cocos2d which is supposed to emulate the OpenGL version and it seems that when I try to tinker with any of the values, my cube disappears.

**My question is:** Can you provide a `gluLookAt()` usage here that will get me started manipulating the camera so I can figure out how this works? I'm really just interesting in learning how to tilt the camera along the Y axis.

Here is my current code:

**Viewport Configuration**

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, _viewFramebuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);
```

**Projection Matrix**

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

// Maybe this should be a perspective projection?? If so,
// can you provide an example using gluPerspective()?
glOrthof(-_backingWidth, _backingWidth,-_backingHeight, _backingHeight, -1, 1);
```

**ModelView Matrix**

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt() // What goes here?
```

**Drawing Code**

```
static const GLfloat cubeVertices[] = {
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
};

static const GLushort cubeIndices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 7, 6, 2, 4, 0, 1
};

static const GLubyte cubeColors[] = {
    255, 255,   0, 255,
    0,   255, 255, 255,
    0,     0,   0,   0,
    255,   0, 255, 255,
    255, 255,   0, 255,
    0,   255, 255, 255,
    0,     0,   0,   0,
    255,   0, 255, 255
};

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cubeColors);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndices);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what exactly you want, but here some explanations:

`gluLookAt` expects 3 vectors (each as 3 doubles): first the position of the camera (eye point), then the position to where you look (center point) and finally an up-vector that specifies an up-direction (this need not be the perfect orthogonal upward direction, as it is reorthogonalized anyway).

So if you stand at (0,0,5) and look at your cube (that is at the center) and want the y-axis to be the up-direction, you would call `gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` to see your cube in full beauty.

If you want to tilt your head to the side, you just need to change the up-vector and rotate it to the side a bit. Or if you want to look up, but without tilting the head to the side, you still use the y-axis as up-vector, but you just look at another point, so you change the center point to a point above and in front of you (maybe rotated about the eye position). But this won't work if you want to look straight up, in this case you need to change the up-vector to something orthogonal to the y-axis (in addition to setting the center point to a point straight above you, of course).

But I think you want a perspective projection. Your current ortho is at least quite inappropriate for your coordinates, as it specifies a coordinate system in which coordinates are in the size of pixel, so your [-1,1]-cube is about the size of a pixel on the screen. Try `gluPerspective(60.0, ((double)_backingWidth)/_backingHeight, 0.1, 100.0)`. If you really want an orthographic projection without any realistic perspective distortion, you can use `glOrtho`, but in this case you should keep the size proprtions of the `glOrtho` parameters and your model's coordinates roughly in-sync (therefore not specify a screen-sized ortho and using coordinates in the [-1,1] range).

Comment: @Christan - Thanks, It's beginning to make sense. One more question: if I manipulate the third set of doubles (the up direction), I would expect my cube to move along the Y axis, is this correct?

Comment: @Jesse No, not neccessarily. The up-vector specifies the upward direction of the camera (say the tripod of a real camera). When you manipulate it, you cube will probably rotate perpendicular to the screen. To make it move alogn the y-axis (corresponding to you looking up-ward), you need to change the eye or center position. For example if you move the center position up (along the y-axis) you will look at a point above the cube (and therefore the cube moves, or more exactly rotates, down on the screen). To move it down perpendicular to the screen, chage the eye and the center point.

Comment: @Jesse The `gluLookAt` function is used to specify the camera position and orientation. It should not be used to move your cube in world space (or it's at least not that easy, which might explain your problems). For this you should use the standard OpenGL transformation functions, like `glTranslate`, `glRotate` and `glScale`.

Comment: I don't want to move the cube; rather, I want to move tilt the camera (which will move and distort the cube on screen). I've notice that I can do that by manipulating the look at point. Perfect. Thanks for all your help.