# OpenGL is not displaying anything when looking along the y axis

Tags: opengl

I am currently trying to display a red grid viewed from the top using SFML and OpenGL.
The grid plan is normal to the y axis (y axis is the vector looking to the top).

This is called before my rendering loop:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gluPerspective(90.0f, (GLfloat)640/(GLfloat)480, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Inside my rendering loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0, -3.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.8, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

for (float x = -10.0f, x < 10.0f, x += 1.0f) {
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(x, -0.5f, -10.0f);
        glVertex3f(x, -0.5f, 10.0f);
        glVertex3f(-10.0f, -0.5f, x);
        glVertex3f(10.0f, -0.5f, x);
    glEnd();
}

window.display(); // swap buffers in SFML
```

I stripped the SFML part.

When I replace the gluLookAt(); part by this one (slight tilt of the camera):

```
gluLookAt(0.0, -3.0, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.8, 0.01,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

or this one:
    gluLookAt(0.0, -3.0, 0.0,
        0.0, -0.8, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

Everything is displayed fine.

I concluded that when I look exactly in the -y direction (90°), nothing is drawn. But why? Did I miss something?

My OpenGL supported version is 2.1 Mesa 10.2.4

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you up-axis also points towards the y-axis. It is not necessary that the up-vector points exactly upwards, but it has to be different from your viewing-direction. For more details have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293836/help-understanding-glulookat)

Edit: Since requested, here is the mathematical explaination:

gluLookAt generates a 3d coordinate frame, that consists of three perpendicular vectors.
Assuming the input to gluLookAt is a camera position (C), a eye-position (E), and a up-vector (U), than the matrix is constructed using the following equations:

```
F = C - E
f = F / |F|

U' = U / |U|
```

this results in two vectors that span a plane. We already know, that f (the view-vector) will be the -z axis of our final coordinate frame (opengl looks always along the negative z-axis). The x-axis can be calculated by finding the normal vector of the plane spanned by f and u and can thus be calculated via

```
S = f x U' (x is the cross product)
s = S / |S|
```

Note that the normalization would not be required if u and f are already perpendicular, but since gluLookAt does not require the real up vector this is not necessarily given. Out of the same reason we cannot use u directly as y-axis. What we are looking for is a y-vector that is perpendicular to both, f and s, which is given as:

```
u = s x f
```

The final matrix is than constructed by

```
    |     s    0 |
M = |     u    0 |
    |    -f    0 |
    | 0  0  0  1 |
```

Now consider your case where f = U':
When calculating S we get

```
 S = f x U' = U' x U' = [0, 0, 0]
```

Since this gives a null-vector, u will also be a null-vector. In total this results in a matrix where the first two rows are all zero, and thus each vector multiplied with this matrix will end up with x and y beeing 0.

Hope this helps you. The formulas for gluLookAt are taken from [here](http://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/gluLookAt)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any technical informations about why my viewing direction can't be exactly the same as the up-axis?

Comment: I've added the mathematical explanation to the answer

Comment: That make sense! To give you the full story, I want to make a game where players can see the world by the top or by the perspective. For the from-the-top camera, I just changed my up-vector to z axis and all is working fine. Thanks again!
By the way, I used Ogre and Irrlicht in the past. I do not remember that I had to do such tricks and I am pretty sure that I could look in every directions. I'm wondering how the camera is implemented...