# Looking along z axis gluLookAt works when theta=360 but not when theta=0

Tags: opengl

I was playing around with rendering a triangle in OpenGL and I came across an interesting problem. Obviously, when you look along the 'Up' direction, which in my case means that Eye_z=Up_z (and since I was working in spherical coordinates, this means that theta=0), the object is not displayed (refer to the top answer to [OpenGL is not displaying anything when looking along the y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524013/opengl-is-not-displaying-anything-when-looking-along-the-y-axis) for a mathematical explanation).
However, when I make the angle 360 degrees instead of 0, the object gets displayed without any problem. Does anyone know why? I've attached snippets of my code along with a screenshot here:

triangle.cpp

```
void Triangle::render(Camera C){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glLoadIdentity(); 
        float th = C.Getth();
        float ph = C.Getph();

        float Eye_x = r*sin(th*DEGtoRAD)*cos(ph*DEGtoRAD);
        float Eye_y = r*sin(th*DEGtoRAD)*sin(ph*DEGtoRAD);
        float Eye_z = r*cos(th*DEGtoRAD);

        float Up_z = (th>=180.0f && th<360.0f)?-1.0f:1.0f;

        gluLookAt(Eye_x,Eye_y,Eye_z,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,Up_z); 
        glRotatef(m_rotationAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Draw Triangle
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);
                glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);
                glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.5f,0.0f);
        glEnd();

        // Draw Axes
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
                glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                glVertex3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glEnd();
}
```

camera.cpp:

```
void Camera::Move(int dir){
        switch(dir){
                case 1: // +th
                        th += move_amt;
                        if(th>360.0f){
                                th-=360.0f;
                        }
                        break;
                case -1: // -th
                        th -= move_amt;
                        if(th<=0.0f){
                                th+=360.0f;
                        }
                        break;
                case 2: // ph
                        ph += move_amt;
                        if(ph>=360.0f){
                                ph-=360.0f;
                        }
                        break;
                case -2: // -ph
                        ph -= move_amt;
                        if(ph<=0.0f){
                                ph+=360.0f;
                        }

                        break;
                default:
                        break;
        }
}
```

[This is what I get when Theta=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae4W4.png)

[This is what I get when Theta=360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/899lc.png)

Comment: Likely your `th` isn't really '0' nor '360', but something near. For the case you get a "true" '0' your **eye to target** vector will be parallel to **up**

Comment: I had considered the error in my 360*DEGtoRAD, but how large does it have to be to work? (Or, in other words, how small a change do you need to not be parallel to the Up vector?) My present code has the degree to radian conversion accurate to 6 digits.